# Can I use a linked list with a tree structure and Lee's algorithm to solve a maze quickly?

Tags: c, linked-list, tree, maze

For a university assignment I have to solve a maze as quickly as possible. This wasn't difficult to implement using a normal implementation of Lee's algorithm.

With a maze such as this one: [image: Maze]

Now I would like to eliminate the need for backtracking (iteratively searching for the next lowest node) by saving the shortest path in a linked list.

I thought if I had a tree where each node on the maze is connected to every node it is adjacent to. When I find the target, I can just iterate through the parent connections to find the shortest route.

This is how I imagine it visually:

[image: This is how I imagine it visually]

I wrote the following code to try to implement this:

```
//Define node struct//
struct node
{
   int i;
   int y, x;
   struct node *parent, *child;
};
//Define node struct//
 
void CreateNode(struct node *head, int x, int y, int i)
{
    struct node *new, *el; //Instantiate new node and iterating node
    new=malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Assign memory
    new->y = y; new->x = x; new->i = i; //Assign data
    new->child=NULL;
    el=head; //Iterate from head
   
   while(el->child != NULL)
   {
      if((el->x == x + 1 || el->x == x - 1 || el->y == y + 1 || el->y == y -1) && el->i == i + 2) //check wether node is adjacent
      {
         new->parent = el; //create 'tree' parent connection if node is adjacent
         break;
      }
   }
   

   el = head; 
   while(el->child != NULL)
   {
      el = el->child; //Add new element as last element in linear linked list
   }
   el->child = new;
}

void LinkedLee(int obstructions, int xObstructPos[], int yObstructPos[], int xStartPos, int yStartPos, int xTargetPos, int yTargetPos){
   
   //Instantiate head & last node//
   struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
   head->x = xTargetPos;
   head->y = yTargetPos;
   head->i = 1;
   head->child = NULL;
   head->parent = NULL;

   struct node *last = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   last = head;
   //Instantiate head & last node//

   int i = 1;
   int x, y = 0;
   field[xTargetPos][yTargetPos] = i;

   for(int i = 0; i < obstructions; i++) //Place obstructions
   {
      field[xObstructPos[i]][yObstructPos[i]] = -1; //-1 represents obstructions in the field matrix
   }

   while(field[xStartPos][yStartPos] == 0){
      for(y=0; y<13; y++) {
         for(x=0; x<13; x++) {
            if(field[x][y] == i){ //Check if this coords adjacent to this coord can be taken
               if(field[x + 1][y] == 0 && x != 12)
               {
                  field[x + 1][y] = i + 1;
                  if(i % 2) //Check if coordinate is a node or an edge (all nodes are uneven)
                  {
                     CreateNode(head, ((x + 1)/2 - 1), (y/2 - 1), i); //Create node
                     last = last->child;
                     printf("created node");
                  }
               }

               if(field[x - 1][y] == 0 && x != 0)
               {
                  field[x - 1][y] = i + 1;
                  if(i % 2)
                  {
                     CreateNode(head, ((x + 1)/2 - 1), (y/2 -1), i);
                     last = last->child;
                     printf("created node");
                  }
               }

               if(field[x][y + 1] == 0 && y != 12)
               {
                  field[x][y + 1] = i + 1;
                  if(i % 2)
                  {
                     CreateNode(head, (x/2 - 1), ((y + 1)/2 -1), i);
                     last = last->child;
                     printf("created node");
                  }
               }

               if(field[x][y - 1] == 0 && y != 0)
               {
                  field[x][y - 1] = i + 1;
                  if(i % 2)
                  {
                     CreateNode(head, (x/2 - 1), ((y - 1)/2 - 1), i);
                     last = last->child;
                     printf("created node");
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```

When I implement this I get segmentation faults, which I dont fully understand currently to be honest. I hope someone here could help me to understand if this idea is possible and why my implementation doesnt work.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

I wrote a minimal reproducible example (as best I could). It executes and it allows you to view the result in terminal. This is the simple maze I used to make it:

[image: The maze]

(For the 'field' I use field/maze coordinates because those are easier for people to remember and I need to use them like that later in this project.)

The code for the reproducible example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Define node struct//
struct node
{
  int i;
  int y, x;
  struct node *parent, *child;
};
//Define node struct//

//Instantiate functions
void CreateField(); //Fill field matrix
void PrintField(); //Print field matrix
void CreateNode(struct node *head, struct node *last, int x, int y, int i); //Create a path node
void LinkedLee(int obstructions, int obstructPos[9][2], int startTerminal, int targetTerminal);
void TerminalToCoord(int terminal, int * terminalPos); //Translate terminals to pointers to matrix coordinates
int FieldCoordToCoord(int fieldCoord); //Translate maze coordinates to matrix coordinates
int CoordToFieldCoord(int coord); //Translate matrix coordinates to maze coordinates
//Instantiate functions

int size = 9; //Instantiate with size 9;
int field[9][9] = { {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                   {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                   {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1} }; //Instantiate Field with size 9;
int path[15][2]; //Instantiate array to store path;
int obstructPos[9][2] = {{0,0}}; //Instantiate array with positions of obstructions in field coords

int main() {
   CreateField();
   LinkedLee(1, obstructPos, 1, 4);
   PrintField();
   return 0;
}

void CreateField()
{
  int x, y;
  for(y=0; y < size; y++) 
   {
       for(x=0; x < size; x++) 
       {
           if(x == 4 || y == 4)
           {
               field[x][y] = 0;
           }
           if(((x < 7 && x > 1) && (y == 2 || y == 6)) || ((y < 7 && y > 1) && (x == 2 || x == 6)))
           {
               field[x][y] = 0;
           }
       }
   }
}

void PrintField()
{
  int x, y;
   for(y=0; y < size; y++) {
     for(x=0; x < size; x++) {
        if(field[x][y] == -1)
        {
           printf("\033[0;31m"); //Print in red
        } else {
           printf("\033[0;32m"); //Print in green
        }

        printf("%d",field[x][y]); printf("\t"); //Print the value of current coord
     }
     printf("\033[0;37m%d\t", y); //print y-axis label in white
     printf("\n\v");
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
     printf("\033[0;37m%d\t", i); //Print x-axis label
  }
  printf("\033[0;37m\n\n\n"); //print 3 newlines & print in white
}

void LinkedLee(int obstructions, int obstructPos[9][2], int startTerminal, int targetTerminal)
{
   //Instantiate function variables
   int distanceFromTarget = 1;
   int x, y = 0;

   //Translate terminals into target & start coordinates
   int * targetPos; targetPos = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   int * startPos ; startPos = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
   TerminalToCoord(startTerminal, startPos); //Get coords of start terminal (*startPos, *(startPos + 1))
   TerminalToCoord(targetTerminal, targetPos); //Get coord of target terminal (*targetPos, *(targetPos + 1))

   printf("Starting with target terminal %d, stopping at start terminal %d.\n", targetTerminal, startTerminal);
   //Instantiate head & last node//
   struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
   head->x = CoordToFieldCoord(*targetPos);
   head->y = CoordToFieldCoord(*(targetPos + 1));
   head->i = distanceFromTarget;
   head->child = NULL;
   head->parent = NULL;

   struct node *last = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
   last = head;
   //Instantiate head & last node//
   
   field[*targetPos][*(targetPos + 1)] = distanceFromTarget; //Flood target terminal

   for(int j = 0; j < obstructions; j++) //Translate obstruction field coords to coords and place obstruction
   {
       field[FieldCoordToCoord(obstructPos[j][0])][FieldCoordToCoord(obstructPos[j][1])] = -1; 
   }

   while(field[*startPos][*(startPos + 1)] == 0){                              //Until the start coord is flooded ->
       for(y=0; y < size; y++) {                                               //For every y
           for(x=0; x < size; x++) {                                           //For every x
               if(field[x][y] == distanceFromTarget){                          //Check if current coord was just flooded
                   if(field[x + 1][y] == 0 && x != 12)                         //Check if any adjacent coord is empty
                   {
                       field[x + 1][y] = distanceFromTarget + 1;
                       if(distanceFromTarget % 2)
                       {
                           CreateNode(head, last, CoordToFieldCoord(x), CoordToFieldCoord(y), distanceFromTarget);
                           printf("created node\n");
                       }
                   }
                    if(field[x - 1][y] == 0 && x != 0)                         //Check if any adjacent coord is empty
                   {
                       field[x - 1][y] = distanceFromTarget + 1;
                       if(distanceFromTarget % 2)
                       {
                           CreateNode(head, last, CoordToFieldCoord(x), CoordToFieldCoord(y), distanceFromTarget);
                           printf("created node\n");
                       }
                   }
                    if(field[x][y + 1] == 0 && y != 12)                         //Check if any adjacent coord is empty
                   {
                       field[x][y + 1] = distanceFromTarget + 1;
                       if(distanceFromTarget % 2)
                       {
                           CreateNode(head, last, CoordToFieldCoord(x), CoordToFieldCoord(y), distanceFromTarget);
                           printf("created node\n");
                       }
                   }
                    if(field[x][y - 1] == 0 && y != 0)                         //Check if any adjacent coord is empty
                   {
                       field[x][y - 1] = distanceFromTarget + 1;
                       if(distanceFromTarget % 2)
                       {
                           CreateNode(head, last, CoordToFieldCoord(x), CoordToFieldCoord(y), distanceFromTarget);
                           printf("created node\n");
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       distanceFromTarget++;
   }

   free(targetPos);
   free(startPos);
}

void CreateNode(struct node *head, struct node *last ,int x, int y, int i)
{
   struct node *new, *el; //Instantiate new node and iterating node
   new=malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Assign memory
   new->y = y; new->x = x; new->i = i; //Assign data
   new->child=NULL;
   el=head; //Iterate from head
  
   if(el->child = NULL)
   {
       new->parent = el;
   } else {
       while(el->child != NULL)
       {
           int elPlace = FieldCoordToCoord(el->child->x) + FieldCoordToCoord(el->child->y);
           int newPlace = FieldCoordToCoord(x) + FieldCoordToCoord(y);
           if((newPlace + 1 == elPlace || newPlace - 1 == elPlace) && el->child->i == i + 2) //check wether node is adjacent
           {
               new->parent = el; // 
               break;
           }
       }
   }

   last->child = new;
   last = last->child;

   printf("Flooded new node c%d%d, with distance: %d\n", y,x,i);
}

void TerminalToCoord(int terminal, int * terminalPos)
{
   //Translate terminal into coordinates//
   switch(terminal)
   {
       case 1:
           *terminalPos = 4;
           *(terminalPos + 1) = 8;
           break;
       case 2:
           *terminalPos = 8;
           *(terminalPos + 1) = 4;
           break;
       case 3:
           *terminalPos = 4;
           *(terminalPos + 1) = 0;
           break;
       case 4:
           *terminalPos = 0;
           *(terminalPos + 1) = 4;
           break;
       default:
           printf("%d is not a valid terminal value. Please enter a valid terminal.", terminal);
           break;
   }
}

int CoordToFieldCoord(int coord)
{
   int fieldCoord;
   fieldCoord = (coord/2 -1);
   return fieldCoord;
}

int FieldCoordToCoord(int fieldCoord)
{
   int coord;
   coord = (fieldCoord*2 + 1);
   return coord;
}
```

It is long but I was not able to make a shorter example. It executes but does not actually complete the task. I understand if this problem is too complicated for anyone to help. Although, I hope someone might understand the problem better than me.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: *"I get segmentation faults"*: I get that `field` is not defined. And there is no `main`... Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, this is ofcourse not the complete code, this is only the part dealing with the linked list I mentioned. Your response is a little curt to be frank :/

Comment: I hope you understand we are volunteers and happy to help. But if you want us to look into your problem, then please understand that we expect you to help us first and provide code we can actually run to see the problem you talk about. You can read more about [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I get that! I was working on a minimal reproducible example but I haven't got that working yet. So I just made the question with an excerpt from a much larger code hoping someone could offer ideas as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Will you come back to the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here, including:

- `x != 12` is not a good condition; it should be `x < size` and it should be tested *before* using `x` as an index. Similar errors occur the similar `if` conditions. These errors can cause undefined behaviour like segmentation faults.
- In `CreateNode`, if the `while` loop enters, it will never exit, because the loop condition never changes. `el` never changes, so there is no iteration over the linked list either; `el` is only ever equal to `head`.
- In `CreateNode` I don't see how the calculation of `newPlace` makes any sense: it adds x and y coordinates, but that is not uniquely defining a "place". There is a whole diagonal of positions that share the same sum of x and y coordinates.

You can implement the idea of a linked list in a simpler way: create a 2D array `comeFrom` (of `goTo` -- however you see it), much like `field`, but which stores coordinates (much like `path`). Then, when you visit a cell, store at the corresponding entry in `comeFrom` the coordinates of where you came from in the breadth-first search. This way you build an implicit linked list at every visited cell of the field.

Then remains to build the path from that information.

I adapted your code to implement that idea. Note that I removed the notion of obstructions, as I encoded these directly in the `field` definition -- it was not related to your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int i;
  int y, x;
  struct node *parent, *child;
};

int size = 9;
int field[][9] = { {-1,-1,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0,-1,-1},
                    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {-1,-1, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1},
                    {-1,-1,-1,-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1}};
int path[15][2];

void printField() {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            printf("\033[0;3%dm%d\t", field[x][y] == -1 ? 1 : 2, field[x][y]); //Print in red or green
        }
        printf("\033[0;37m%d\t\n\v", y); //print y-axis label in white
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) {
        printf("\033[0;37m%d\t", i); //Print x-axis label
    }
    printf("\033[0;37m\n\n\n"); //print 3 newlines & print in white
}

int linkedLee(int startX, int startY, int targetX, int targetY) {
    int distanceFromTarget = 1;
    // This represents the "linked list": each cell can point to a neighbor:
    int comeFrom[size][size][2]; 
    // The four directions we can move
    int dx[] = {1, 0, -1, 0};
    int dy[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    
    field[targetY][targetX] = distanceFromTarget;
    while (1) {
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                if (field[y][x] == distanceFromTarget) {
                    if (x == startX && y == startY) { // bingo!
                        // Build path from comeFrom (linked list)
                        path[0][0] = x;
                        path[0][1] = y;
                        int i = 1;
                        while (x != targetX || y != targetY) {
                            int *pair = comeFrom[y][x];
                            x = path[i][0] = pair[0];
                            y = path[i][1] = pair[1];
                            i++;
                        }
                        return i;
                    }
                    for (int dir = 0; dir < 4; dir++) {
                        int x1 = x + dx[dir];
                        int y1 = y + dy[dir];
                        if (y1 >= 0 && x1 >= 0 && y1 < size && x1 < size && field[y1][x1] == 0) { 
                            // field is available and not visited yet
                            field[y1][x1] = distanceFromTarget + 1;
                            comeFrom[y1][x1][0] = x;
                            comeFrom[y1][x1][1] = y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        distanceFromTarget++;
    }
}

void printPath(int pathSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pathSize; i++) {
        printf("(%d,%d) ", path[i][0], path[i][1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int pathSize = linkedLee(0, 4, 4, 0);
    printField();
    printPath(pathSize);
    return 0;
}
```